# PhoneGap Android RevMob plugin ads not showing..

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, revmobads

Hi I am new to the Ads Monetization in RevMob.. I am trying phonegap plugins for android and followed this link to implement http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html but nothing is displaying on the screen.. I have tried with their example also BUT in that also getting error "Session has not been start. Call the start session method" in logcat. I called startSession method then also getting same error.
Please anybody help to resolve this..
I have googled BUT no luck

Comment: I'm not very used in revMob. If you where interested in Admob, I've developed a cordova/phonegap plugin wich it works fine. You can install it with `cordova plugin add com.admob.google` or `phonegap local add plugin https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.git`. [See documentation here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding google play services as library in the project. We need to check the copy project into workspace while importing google play services libproject
Thank you